# How do I prevent white flash between images?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

[image]

I'd like the current image to fade out at the same time that the next image fades in (like the second image above), with no white flash in between. I feel like it has something to do with the javascript, but I can't detect what's wrong. Any advice?

Here's the component code:

```
const ImageSlider = ({ slides }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length;

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
  };

  if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <section className="slider">
      <FaArrowAltCircleLeft className="left-arrow" onClick={prevSlide} />
      {SliderData.map((slide, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={index === current ? "slide active" : "slide"}
            key={slide.id}
          >
            {index === current && (
              <img src={slide.img} alt="" className="image" />
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <FaArrowAltCircleRight className="right-arrow" onClick={nextSlide} />
    </section>
  );
};

export default ImageSlider;
```

And the css:

```
.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}

.image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 200ms opacity ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-delay: 0ms;
}
.slide > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
```

Comment: For small number of images you can render them all: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-resonance-hdq4sq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @user4980215. This solution achieved the desired result with minimal changes in my original markup. Looks like I just need to get rid of index === current &&, and a few changes in css. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

The OP wanted both the images to have a an animation. But this is currently not possible. Why?

Because of this statement:

```
            {index === current && (
              <img src={slide.img} alt="" className="image" />
            )}
```

There is only one image to be shown at a time. The one whose `index` is matching with `current`. So there is only one image in the `DOM`. There is no chance of having one image fade in while the other fades out.

To achieve something like that I would prefer having two images in the `DOM` at the same time. One current and one previous.

We keep updating the previous value into another state variable.

```
const ImageSlider = ({ slides }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const [prevCurrent, setPrevCurrent] = useState(-1);
  const length = SliderData.length;

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setPrevCurrent(current);
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setPrevCurrent(current);
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
  };

  if (!Array.isArray(SliderData) || SliderData.length <= 0) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <section className="slider">
      <button className="left-arrow" onClick={nextSlide}>
        Left
      </button>
      {SliderData.map((slide, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className={index === current ? "slide active" : "slide hide"}
            key={slide.id}
          >
            {index === current && (
              <img src={slide.img} alt="" className="image" />
            )}
            {prevCurrent > -1 && index === prevCurrent && (
              <img src={slide.img} alt="" className="image" />
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button className="right-arrow" onClick={prevSlide}>
        Right
      </button>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Updated the css to something like this. Having the `hide` and `active` classes separate can help you easily use this somewhere else too.

```
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out;
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Updated Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-dijkstra-ufhrqi) [Demo](https://k91rnw.csb.app/)

Earlier it was assumed that the fade effect was required only for one image. Without changing the JS code, it could be achieved like this:

**PREVIOUS:**

Changed your css to this and it worked:

```
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

If we keep a transition delay in `.active` which is much higher than the one in non-active state, then we will see a blank screen. So removed that too.

Here is a sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-breeze-k91rnw?file=/src/styles.css) of my fix.
I had to increase the duration a bit so I could notice the effect. You can tweak around to see your desired effect, like a delay of 3s is really peaceful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried both the css in your response and in the sandbox (they were different), but can't get the desired effect. The current image disappears immediately with no fade out effect on click, then there's a brief white screen, then the next image slowly fades in. I would like the current image to fade out at the same rate as the next image fades in with no white space in between.

Comment: Then the way to do it would be by changing your JS code a bit. Please update your question while I fix the solution

Comment: @Chris check link now

Comment: Your solution works, so thank you very much. I went with the solution provided in user4980215's comment since it required only minimal changes to my original code.